# How can i get rid of the stroke in google charts?

Tags: css, charts, google-visualization

I want to get rid of the stroke in my google charts - donut.

I tried this:

```
'chartArea': {
                width:'80%',
                height:'80%',
                stroke:'black',
                strokeSize: 0
            },
```

I want to get the following effect:
[following :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzQul.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the border color property to transparent like this.

```
new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
  draw(data, {
                pieSliceBorderColor : "transparent"

              }
      );
```